# running maven task on spring cloud data flow in kubernetes platform

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to setup spring cloud data flow to be able to run maven tasks in kubernetes cluster.
I was able to register repository in the SCDF server, and register application with maven://group:artifact:version but when I try to launch the corresponding task SCDF creates pod with

```
    image: maven://....
```

so kubernetes says that image name is incorrect.

Is there a way to make SCDF use jars from maven repo in kubernetes platform?
Or does kubernetes platform supports only docker:// type tasks?

I tried to check if docker type task works and it is.
I would like to have maven type tasks to be working as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow uses Spring Cloud Deployer for Kubernetes and it only deploys container images.
If you have maven coordinates for a Spring Boot JAR and you want to create a container the easiest is to use [Paketo pack cli](https://buildpacks.io/docs/for-platform-operators/how-to/integrate-ci/pack/).

Then use:

```
pack build \
    --path <path-to-jar> \
    --builder gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/builder:base <container-repository>/<container-image>:<image-tag>
```